# Typescript: return value after delay

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a get request which is an asynchornouns method. To **fetch** the data, i make a delay for 3 seconds, and after that, **i  expect to return the result.** Here is the code:

```
getWeatherForcastWithLocation(){

             this._http.get(uri)
                    .subscribe( res =>this.setItems(res.json(),false));
            setTimeout(()=>{ 
                     return this.weatherStatatistic; 
            },3000);        

    return null;
}
```

I would like to return `this.weatherStatatistic`, however,  it always returns `null`. I know it's because of  `return null;`at the end of the method, but if i remove it the return type of method would be `void`.
So **how can i return** `this.weatherStatistic`?

Comment: What happens in `this.setItems`?

Comment: it just set the json values in the weatherStatistic

Comment: By the way, think you should read up on the concept of promises. Normally you would return the this._$http request, and to get the response something like `this. getWeatherForcastWithLocation().then((res) => {})` where the response is handled inside the curly brackets.

Comment: Then I suggest trying to log what happens in setItems to debug it

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the function in to a promise or an observable. Or simpler just return the http request and on the other end set the timeout.

Something like this:

```
getWeatherForcastWithLocation(){
  return this._http.get(uri).map(res => this.setItems(res.json(),false))
}

// In the receiving funtion
someFunction() {
    setTimeout(() => /* code to execute */, 3000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not return a value from an async operation (unless you use the new async/await feature of `ES2017`), but you have two options:

(1) Pass a callback to receive the data when ready:

```
getWeatherForcastWithLocation(cb: (stats: any) => void) {
    this._http.get(uri)
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.setItems(res.json(), false);
            cb(this.weatherStatatistic);
        });
}
```

(2) Return a promise to the data:

```
getWeatherForcastWithLocation(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this._http.get(uri)
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.setItems(res.json(), false);
                resolve(this.weatherStatatistic);
            });
    });
}
```